# OrderDelivery requires shippingCosts even though it should not according to the documentation Shopware 6 Admin API

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api

I am trying to create a new OrderDelivery entry using the Shopware Admin API. To do this I am using this [api](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/admin-api/c2NoOjE0MzUxMjc1-order-delivery). According to the [documentation](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/admin-api/c2NoOjE0MzUxMjc1-order-delivery) it should not be required to supply the field shippingCosts, but when I send my request

```
{ "trackingCode": [ "328432328" ], "shippingMethodId": "THE_ID_OF_THE_SHIPPING_METHOD", "shippingOrderAddressId": "THE_ADDRESS_ID", "stateId": "THE_STATE_ID", "shippingDateEarliest": "2022-07-07T00:00:00.000+00:00", "shippingDateLatest": "2022-07-07T00:00:00.000+00:00" }
```

via POST to https://myshopwareinstance/api/order/ORDER_ID/deliveries, I receive a 500 Error response code. The response looks like this:

```
{
"errors": [
    {
        "code": "0",
        "status": "500",
        "title": "Internal Server Error",
        "detail":"An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO `order_delivery` (`id`, `version_id`, `order_id`, `order_version_id`, `shipping_order_address_id`, `shipping_order_address_version_id`, `shipping_method_id`, `state_id`, `tracking_codes`, `shipping_date_earliest`, `shipping_date_latest`, `created_at`) VALUES ('���9hL?��Y�F]m�','���jK¾K��u,4%','\u000b���aBF�����z�','���jK¾K��u,4%','��L�!F[���$KU��','���jK¾K��u,4%','���7K���X�&�� ','IA��XJ*�4���\\\"�','[]','2022-07-12 00:00:00.000','2022-07-12 00:00:00.000','2022-07-19 08:52:42.928');':\n\nSQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'shipping_costs' doesn't have a default value",
        "meta": {
            "trace": [
                {
                    "file": "/shopwaredir/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DBALException.php",
                    "line": 182,
                    "function": "convertException",
                    "class": "Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\AbstractMySQLDriver",
                    "type": "->"
                },
                {
                    "file": "/shopwaredir/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DBALException.php",
                    "line": 159,
                    "function": "wrapException",
                    "class": "Doctrine\\DBAL\\DBALException",
                    "type": "::"
                },
                {
                    "file": "/shopwaredir/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php",
                    "line": 2226,
                    "function": "driverExceptionDuringQuery",
                    "class": "Doctrine\\DBAL\\DBALException",
                    "type": "::"
                },
                {
                    "file": "/shopwaredir/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php",
                    "line": 1538,
                    "function": "handleExceptionDuringQuery",
                    "class": "Doctrine\\DBAL\\Connection",
                    "type": "->"
                },
                {
                    "file": "/shopwaredir/vendor/shopware/core/Framework/DataAbstractionLayer/Doctrine/MultiInsertQueryQueue.php",
                    "line": 89,
                    "function": "executeStatement",
                    "class": "Doctrine\\DBAL\\Connection",
                    "type": "->"
                },
                {
                    "file": "/shopwaredir/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php",
                    "line": 1670,
                    "function": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\DataAbstractionLayer\\Doctrine\\{closure}",
                    "class": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\DataAbstractionLayer\\Doctrine\\MultiInsertQueryQueue",
                    "type": "->"
                },
                {
                    "file": "/shopwaredir/vendor/shopware/core/Framework/DataAbstractionLayer/Doctrine/RetryableTransaction.php",
                    "line": 30,
                    "function": "transactional",
                    "class": "Doctrine\\DBAL\\Connection",
                    "type": "->"
                },
                {
                    "file": "/shopwaredir/vendor/shopware/core/Framework/DataAbstractionLayer/Doctrine/RetryableTransaction.php",
                    "line": 19,
                    "function": "retry",
                    "class": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\DataAbstractionLayer\\Doctrine\\RetryableTransaction",
                    "type": "::"
                },
                {
                    "file": "/shopwaredir/vendor/shopware/core/Framework/DataAbstractionLayer/Doctrine/MultiInsertQueryQueue.php",
                    "line": 91,
                    "function": "retryable",
                    "class": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\DataAbstractionLayer\\Doctrine\\RetryableTransaction",
                    "type": "::"
                },
                {
                    "file": "/shopwaredir/vendor/shopware/core/Framework/DataAbstractionLayer/Dbal/EntityWriteGateway.php",
                    "line": 245,
                    "function": "execute",
                    "class": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\DataAbstractionLayer\\Doctrine\\MultiInsertQueryQueue",
                    "type": "->"
                },
                {
                    "file": "/shopwaredir/vendor/shopware/core/Framework/DataAbstractionLayer/Dbal/EntityWriteGateway.php",
                    "line": 141,
                    "function": "executeCommands",
                    "class": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\DataAbstractionLayer\\Dbal\\EntityWriteGateway",
                    "type": "->"
                },
                {
                    "file": "/shopwaredir/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php",
                    "line": 1670,
                    "function": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\DataAbstractionLayer\\Dbal\\{closure}",
                    "class": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\DataAbstractionLayer\\Dbal\\EntityWriteGateway",
                    "type": "->"
                },
                {
                    "file": "/shopwaredir/vendor/shopware/core/Framework/DataAbstractionLayer/Doctrine/RetryableTransaction.php",
                    "line": 30,
                    "function": "transactional",
                    "class": "Doctrine\\DBAL\\Connection",
                    "type": "->"
                },
                {
                    "file": "/shopwaredir/vendor/shopware/core/Framework/DataAbstractionLayer/Doctrine/RetryableTransaction.php",
                    "line": 19,
                    "function": "retry",
                    "class": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\DataAbstractionLayer\\Doctrine\\RetryableTransaction",
                    "type": "::"
                },
                {
                    "file": "/shopwaredir/vendor/shopware/core/Framework/DataAbstractionLayer/Dbal/EntityWriteGateway.php",
                    "line": 142,
                    "function": "retryable",
                    "class": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\DataAbstractionLayer\\Doctrine\\RetryableTransaction",
                    "type": "::"
                },
                {
                    "file": "/shopwaredir/vendor/shopware/core/Framework/DataAbstractionLayer/Write/EntityWriter.php",
                    "line": 207,
                    "function": "execute",
                    "class": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\DataAbstractionLayer\\Dbal\\EntityWriteGateway",
                    "type": "->"
                },
                {
                    "file": "/shopwaredir/vendor/shopware/core/Framework/DataAbstractionLayer/Write/EntityWriter.php",
                    "line": 143,
                    "function": "write",
                    "class": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\DataAbstractionLayer\\Write\\EntityWriter",
                    "type": "->"
                },
                {
                    "file": "/shopwaredir/vendor/shopware/core/Framework/DataAbstractionLayer/VersionManager.php",
                    "line": 118,
                    "function": "insert",
                    "class": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\DataAbstractionLayer\\Write\\EntityWriter",
                    "type": "->"
                },
                {
                    "file": "/shopwaredir/vendor/shopware/core/Framework/DataAbstractionLayer/EntityRepository.php",
                    "line": 157,
                    "function": "insert",
                    "class": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\DataAbstractionLayer\\VersionManager",
                    "type": "->"
                },
                {
                    "file": "/shopwaredir/vendor/shopware/core/Framework/Api/Controller/ApiController.php",
                    "line": 916,
                    "function": "create",
                    "class": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\DataAbstractionLayer\\EntityRepository",
                    "type": "->"
                },
                {
                    "file": "/shopwaredir/vendor/shopware/core/Framework/Context.php",
                    "line": 207,
                    "function": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\Api\\Controller\\{closure}",
                    "class": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\Api\\Controller\\ApiController",
                    "type": "->"
                },
                {
                    "file": "/shopwaredir/vendor/shopware/core/Framework/Api/Controller/ApiController.php",
                    "line": 934,
                    "function": "scope",
                    "class": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\Context",
                    "type": "->"
                },
                {
                    "file": "/shopwaredir/vendor/shopware/core/Framework/Api/Controller/ApiController.php",
                    "line": 818,
                    "function": "executeWriteOperation",
                    "class": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\Api\\Controller\\ApiController",
                    "type": "->"
                },
                {
                    "file": "/shopwaredir/vendor/shopware/core/Framework/Api/Controller/ApiController.php",
                    "line": 454,
                    "function": "write",
                    "class": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\Api\\Controller\\ApiController",
                    "type": "->"
                },
                {
                    "file": "/shopwaredir/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php",
                    "line": 152,
                    "function": "create",
                    "class": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\Api\\Controller\\ApiController",
                    "type": "->"
                },
                {
                    "file": "/shopwaredir/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php",
                    "line": 74,
                    "function": "handleRaw",
                    "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel",
                    "type": "->"
                },
                {
                    "file": "/shopwaredir/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php",
                    "line": 202,
                    "function": "handle",
                    "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel",
                    "type": "->"
                },
                {
                    "file": "/shopwaredir/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpCache/SubRequestHandler.php",
                    "line": 86,
                    "function": "handle",
                    "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel",
                    "type": "->"
                },
                {
                    "file": "/shopwaredir/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpCache/HttpCache.php",
                    "line": 479,
                    "function": "handle",
                    "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpCache\\SubRequestHandler",
                    "type": "::"
                },
                {
                    "file": "/shopwaredir/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpCache/HttpCache.php",
                    "line": 269,
                    "function": "forward",
                    "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpCache\\HttpCache",
                    "type": "->"
                },
                {
                    "file": "/shopwaredir/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpCache/HttpCache.php",
                    "line": 285,
                    "function": "pass",
                    "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpCache\\HttpCache",
                    "type": "->"
                },
                {
                    "file": "/shopwaredir/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpCache/HttpCache.php",
                    "line": 213,
                    "function": "invalidate",
                    "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpCache\\HttpCache",
                    "type": "->"
                },
                {
                    "file": "/shopwaredir/vendor/shopware/core/HttpKernel.php",
                    "line": 153,
                    "function": "handle",
                    "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpCache\\HttpCache",
                    "type": "->"
                },
                {
                    "file": "/shopwaredir/vendor/shopware/core/HttpKernel.php",
                    "line": 79,
                    "function": "doHandle",
                    "class": "Shopware\\Core\\HttpKernel",
                    "type": "->"
                },
                {
                    "file": "/shopwaredir/public/index.php",
                    "line": 74,
                    "function": "handle",
                    "class": "Shopware\\Core\\HttpKernel",
                    "type": "->"
                }
            ],
            "file": "/shopwaredir/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php",
            "line": 125,
            "previous": [Not included due to limited size of the issue description]
        }
    }
]}
```

I want the field shippingCosts to be auto generated. Is there anything I am doing wrong or is this a bug in Shopware 6?

Answer (score 0):

While the `shippingCosts` object itself may not be required, some of its properties are. This endpoint was meant to persist pre-set data, not to calculate it on the fly.

So the short answer is that you're not doing anything wrong but it's not possible at the moment to achieve what you want. You'd have to calculate the shipping costs on your side.

Longer answer:

You'll have to write a plugin either way.

The first approach would require you to implement your own API controller that gets the `RecalculationService` injected and then call the service's `recalculateOrder` method after persisting your `order_delivery`.

The second approach: There's a recalculation endpoint of the admin api which I can't find documentation for at the moment (might not exist). Since live versions of orders are not allowed to be recalculated, you'll have to create a new version of the order first though: `POST /api/_action/version/order/{orderId}`. This will return a `versionId` for the order. You can use that in the header `sw-version-id` for the request to `POST /api/_action/order/{orderId}/recalculate`. In theory this would recalculate the delivery you persisted before and set the correct shipping costs.

*However*, the `RecalculationService` assembles a sales channel context using the `OrderConverter` at one point and there the permissions `DeliveryProcessor::SKIP_DELIVERY_PRICE_RECALCULATION` and `DeliveryProcessor::SKIP_DELIVERY_TAX_RECALCULATION` are hardcoded to `true`, meaning it actually won't recalculate those in the process. You'd probably have to decorate the `OrderConverter` Service with a plugin anyways and set these two to `false`.